# Error al intentar hacer consultas personalizadas a base de datos Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery, sql

Tengo una tabla en HTML donde se muestra la información que tengo almacenada en una tabla de mi base de datos Mysql y esta información es consultada por medio de ajax. 
Al principio tenia un código que extraía y mostraba toda la data sin tener ninguna opción de busqueda. 
Pero ahora he querido hacer algunos cambios y colocarle unos filtros de búsqueda para que el usuario pueda tener diferentes opciones de consulta personalizadas. El problema es que al intentar armar el codigo sql y ejecutarlo me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object()
>   on boolean in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Fiverr3\fiverr_work2\controlador\DataController.php:91
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Fiverr3\fiverr_work2\controlador\DataController.php on
>   line 91

Al parecer el problema esta en el siguiente código que se encarga de armar la consulta:

```
              $nombre = ["nombre_apellido", "Sin Nombre"]; 
                                $dni = ["dni", ""];
                                $sexo = ["sexo", "Masculino"];
                                $email = ["email", ""];
                                $importar = ["importar", ""];
                                $tipo = "hotmail";
                                $fecha1 = "";
                                $fecha2 = "";


                                $request = "SELECT * FROM tabla2";

                                $objDataTipo = new Data();

                                if($nombre[1] == "" && $dni[1] == "" && $sexo[1] == "" && $email[1] == "" && $fecha1 == "" && $fecha2 == "" && $importar[1] !== "")
                                 {
                                    //extraer data
                                    $request = "SELECT * FROM tabla2 ORDER BY id DESC";
                                 }

                                 else
                                 {
                                    $arrays = [$nombre, $dni, $email, $sexo, $importar];
                                    $request .= "WHERE ";

                                    for($i = 0; $i < count($arrays); $i++)
                                    { 

                                        if($i !== 4)
                                        {
                                            if ($arrays[$i][1] !== "") 
                                            {
                                             $request .= $arrays[$i][0] . " = '". $arrays[$i][1] . "' AND ";
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if ($arrays[$i][1] !== "") 
                                            {
                                                $request .= $arrays[$i][0] ." = ". $arrays[$i][1] . " AND";
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                           if ($fecha1 !== "" && $fecha2 == "") 
                                            {
                                                $request .= " fecha >= '" . $fecha1 ."'";
                                            }

                                            if ($fecha1 == "" && $fecha2 !== "") 
                                            {
                                                $request .= " fecha <= '" . $fecha2 ."'";
                                            }

                                            if ($fecha1 !== "" && $fecha2 !== "") 
                                            {
                                                $request .= " fecha BETWEEN '". $fecha1."' AND '" . $fecha2 . "' ";
                                            }

                                            $request = trim($request, " ");
                                            $request = trim($request, "AND");
                                            $request = trim($request, " ");

                                            $request .= " ORDER BY id DESC";

                                }


                                $objDataTipo = new Data();
                                $query = $objDataTipo->FiltroDeBusqueda($request);
                                $data = Array();
                                $i = 1;
                                $status = "";
                                while ($fetch = $query->fetch_object()) 
                                {
                                    echo $fetch->nombre_apellido;
                                    echo "<br>";

                                    echo $fetch->dni;
                                    echo "<br>";

                                    echo $fetch->email;
                                    echo "<br>";

                                }
```

Esta es la función que ejecuta la consulta

```
              public function FiltroDeBusqueda($sql)
        {
        global $conexion;
        $query = $conexion->query($sql);
        return $query;
        }
```

No se exactamente donde esta fallando el código. La idea es que si el usuario no selecciona ninguna opción le muestre toda la data almacenada sin hacer este filtrado. 
Pero si llega a seleccionar alguna de las opciones de filtrado, que le devuelve de forma correcta los datos.

Comment: Imprime tus eventuales consultas finales y revísalas. De entrada son erróneas porque empiezas así: `SELECT * FROM tabla2 ORDER BY id DESC` y luego le agregas cosas como el `WHERE`. Cualquier consulta que tenga primero `ORDER BY` y después `WHERE` es errónea sintácticamente.

Comment: efectivamente tienes razón, ya vi donde tenia el error. Simplemente quite el order by (porque de hecho no lo estaba necesitando) y funciono. Después probe colocando el order by pero en otra parte del codigo y también me ha funcionado. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Dado que el `ORDER BY` va siempre al final de la consulta, se lo puedes añadir al final, cuando hayas salido de todos los `if` o  sólo cuando te interese tener un orden.

Comment: exacto de hecho eso fue lo que hice, se lo agregue al final y funcionó bien.